# IIS APPPOOL\<PoolName> Application Pool setting ACL in GUI Issue IIS 7.5 on Windows 2008 R2

Tags: iis-7.5, application-pools

I can't seem to input the "IIS APPPOOL\PoolName" 'account' into the Windows file/folder ACL setting GUI, it doesn't recognise the account.

I understand that this was a problem in vanilla Windows 2008 and you needed to use icacls, but it's supposed to work on Windows 2008 R2 in the GUI.

See - http://forums.iis.net/t/1156692.aspx

Any ideas?

Comment: @Christopher Edwards: I just checked and this does work on 2008R2 for me. In the GUI window you have options for "object type" and "location" - make sure that "built-in security principals" is chosen in object type, and that your machine name is chosen in location.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem recently.  After running IISRESET, I was able to assign permissions to the app pool identity accounts through the GUI as expected.